# Awesome WM doesn't appear on choosing session on login

Tags: window-manager, awesome

I've just installed **Awesome** on **Linux Lite 2.0**.

But **awesome** doesn't appear when I’m about to login. There's no option to choose **awesome** during login.

This is the content of my **awesome.desktop** under **/usr/share/xsessions/**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=awesome
Comment=Highly configurable framework window manager
TryExec=awesome
Exec=awesome
Type=Application
```